# Chrome Extension embedding script in active web page, in MV3?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

beautiful people on the internet. I am new to chrome extension not new to writing code though. I have implemented webpack to use external packages. One major one in my application is npm package by the name "mark.js".

My application works like this i want some specific words to be highlighted in active webpage using this package. I have written code for this to achieve the functionality but the problem is with loading the script in a web page. I have performed different aspect of loading script but that doesnot work. The new MV3 version have some strict rules.

I want to achieve anything similar of loading script in an active webpage. Please help.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", async () => {
  console.log("BUTTON IS PRESSED!!");
  try {
    await chrome.tabs.query(
      { active: true, currentWindow: true },
      async function (tabs) {
        
        chrome.scripting.executeScript({
          target: { tabId: tabs[0].id },
          func: highlightText,
          args: [arr],
        });
      }
    );
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("ERROR AT CHROME TAB QUERY : ", e);
  }
});


async function highlightText(arr) {
  console.log(typeof Mark);
  
  try {
    var instance2 = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));
    // instance2.mark("is");

    var success = [];
    // const instance2 = new Mark(document.querySelector("body"));
    await Promise.all(
      arr.map(async function (obj) {
        console.log("OBJECT TEXT : ", obj.text);
        instance2.mark(obj.text, {
          element: "span",
          each: function (ele) {
            console.log("STYLING : ");
            ele.setAttribute("style", `background-color: ${obj.color};`);
            if (obj.title && obj.title != "") {
              ele.setAttribute("title", obj.title);
            }
            ele.innerHTML = obj.text;
            success.push({
              status: "Success",
              text: obj.text,
            });
          },
        });
      })
    );
    console.log("SUCCESS : ", success);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't load it externally. Include it as a script within your extension, then run it just like any other [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts). You can either configure webpack to build this script or just use an [existing bundle](https://unpkg.com/browse/mark.js@8.11.1/dist/).

Comment: @wOxxOm So this is what i did and it still doesnt work, if i am wrong please guide me:
- i have downloaded existing bundle for mark.js and included it in manifest per your instruction as any content script.
`
{
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": [
        "mark.js", "popup.js"
      ]
    }
`

- using chrome.runtime.geturl have that script imported and it stills gives an error of undefined for Mark, instance of mark.js class.

Comment: @wOxxOm please elaborate with a code, please. I am working on this for a week now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use chrome.runtime.getURL. Since you use executeScript to run your code all you need is to inject mark.js before injecting the function.

Also, don't load popup.js in `content_scripts`, it's not a content script (these run in web pages), it's a script for your extension page. Actually, you don't need `content_scripts` at all.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  const target = { tabId: tab.id };
  const exec = v => (await chrome.scripting.executeScript({ target, ...v }))[0].result;
  if (!await exec({ func: () => !!window.Mark })) {
    await exec({files: ['mark.js.min'] });
    await exec({func: highlightText, args: [arr] });
  }
});
```

Comment: I love you man. Thank you so much. Thank you so very much for your precious time.

Comment: I have one last request. Can you explain the exec functions what is happening, especially the first one. That is confusing.

Comment: There was a mistake (I forgot to save the edits), now it should be clear. The exec function waits for executeScript to complete, which returns an array of results, the first item's result is returned which corresponds to the returned value of the injected function: `!!window.Mark` is true if Mark is defined or false otherwise. See also "Destructuring assignment" and "Object spread syntax".

Comment: Great! Much love and appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

For V3 I assume you will want to use Content Scripts in your manifest to inject the javascript into every webpage it matches. I recently open-sourced [TorpedoRead](https://github.com/unreleased/TorpedoRead) and had to do both V2 and V3, I recommend checking the repo as it sounds like I did something similar to you (Firefox is V2, Chrome is V3).

The code below need to be added to your `manifest.json` and this will execute on every page based on the `matches` property. You can read more about content scripts here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/

```js
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
      "js": ["yourscript.js"]
    }
 ],
```

Comment: Thank you for your knowledge and time, really appreciate it. I have copy and paste the code and it is giving me a TypeError of 'result' being undefined.